# How to get list of tables in particular job in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get a list of tables in a particular job

I have a SQL server job which is running daily and manipulating all the data with certain business logic.

Is there a way to get a list of all the tables that are being used/created in a JOB?

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Kindly share your more precise problem.

Comment: added the details

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the table name directly, but you can get all the commands being executed by a job.

From the command you can find which tables are involved.

You can use following query to get the commands associated with a particular job.

```
SELECT j.name,
s.database_name,
s.command
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
ON s.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE s.job_id='PUT JOB ID HERE'
```

**Note:** `job_id` is a unique identifier which is unique for each job. If you want to know the `job_id` of a job with by name, for that you can query the table `msdb.dbo.sysjobs`